# How to make operation between two Aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have this MongoDB schema

```
    {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "56cd9c103ff0020300fa1135"
},
"title": "50x kliky",
"timing": "2x týdně",
"user": "Stejk",
"history": [
    {
        "title": "50x kliky",
        "datum": "11.09.2016",
        "done": false
    },
    {
        "title": "50x kliky",
        "datum": "11.09.2016",
        "done": true
    },
    {
        "title": "50x kliky",
        "datum": "11.09.2016",
        "done": true
    },
    {
        "title": "50x kliky",
        "datum": "11.09.2016",
        "done": true
    },
    {
        "title": "50x kliky",
        "datum": "11.09.2016",
        "done": true
    }
],
"__v": 0
}
```

i have these code

```
    BuzzerListekSchema.statics.getBuzzerListekDetailPercentage = function(req, response, res){
  // Function1
  this.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$history'},
    {$match: {'history.done': true}}, //Filtr
    {$group: {_id: req.params.id, count: {$sum: 1}}}
 ], function(err, c){
   if(err){
     res.status(500).json({succes: false, msg: 'Error'});
   }
   else {
    // Here is result c
    // {_id: ubuiabiufbuiab, count: 5}
   }
 });

 // Function2
 this.aggregate([
   {$unwind: '$history'},
   {$group: {_id: req.params.id, count: {$sum: 1}}}
], function(err, c){
  if(err){
    res.status(500).json({succes: false, msg: 'Error'});
  }
  else {
    // Here is result c
    // {_id: ubuiabiufbuiab, count: 5}
  }
});
  //Here i want reach a percent of percent=Function1/(Function2/100) and send it by JSON
  //res.json({succes: false, msg: percent});

};
```

And i want to make a JSON response with these Function1/(Function2/100).
For more explain see comments inside code. 
How to reach that c from this two functions? 
Please help, iam total noob in these so be patient.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider running the following pipeline to get the desired result:

```
BuzzerListekSchema.statics.getBuzzerListekDetailPercentage = function(req, response, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    var pipeline = [
        { "$match": { "_id": id } },
        { "$unwind": "$history" },          
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": 0,
                "count": { 
                    "$sum": { 
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$history.done", true ] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    } 
                },
                "total": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "percentage":{
                    "$multiply": [
                        { "$divide": [ 100, "$total" ] }, "$count"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    this.aggregate(pipeline)
        .exec(function (err, result){
            if(err){
                res.status(500).json({succes: false, msg: 'Error'});
            }
            else {
                res.json({succes: false, msg: result[0]})
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: and if i have id in req.params.id just replace 0 in _id

Comment: Or better explain if i want just percent for exact _id

Comment: By the way. Thanks lot it works, but with all things in schema

Comment: Please help me :( iam lost :) again.,,... i tried replace _id: 0 with _id: req.params.id but nothing changed

Comment: @JakubStejskal Hard to follow what you want exactly, so I just made a wild educated guess and included the `$match` filter for calculating the percentage for a particular document. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks @chridam

```
BuzzerListekSchema.statics.getBuzzerListekDetailPercentage = function(req, response, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    var pipeline = [
        {"$match": {"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}},
        { "$unwind": "$history" },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "count": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$history.done", true ] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "total": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "percentage":{
                    "$multiply": [
                        { "$divide": [ 100, "$total" ] }, "$count"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ];

    this.aggregate(pipeline)
        .exec(function (err, result){
            if(err){
                res.status(500).json({succes: false, msg: err});
            }
            else {
                res.status(200).json({succes: true, msg: result[0]})
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: With MongoDB 3.2 goodness this is just one pipeline stage: `{ "$project": { "percentage": { "$multiply": [{ "$divide": [{ "$size": { "$filter": { "input": "history", "as": "el", "cond": "$$el.done"  } }}, { "$size": "$history" } ]}, 100 ]} }}`. Which greatly outperforms any processing with `$unwind`. Time to upgrade. Hope this is being performed over more than one document at a time, otherwise it would all be better in client code instead.